# PTIJ: Correct formation of Eli Belly Peanut Butter Jelly

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

**[Maharik 86:](https://www.sefaria.org/Teshuvot_Maharik.86.1)**

> אשר בשעת מילתו
> נקרא אליהו ושוב נקרא בל"י לכל אדם פשיטא ופשיטא דלכתחלה היה לו לכתוב אליהו דמתקרי בלי או המכונה בלי.

> Eliyahu who now goes by Belly, it is more than understood that the appropriate method of inscription is Eliyahu called Belly or known as Belly.

Clearly Maharik is addressing the pet name "Eli-Belly". However, is Maharik specifically discouraging the pet name, since he uses the full name 'Eliyahu'; or does he permit taunting one with Eli-Belly, as long as he says 'Eli who is called Belly'? Furthermore, if this leniency stipulates the addition of 'who is called' as part of the pet name formation, do further taunts, such as 'Eli Belly Peanut Butter Jelly' also require this formation?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: It's not Belly, it's *be'li*, i.e. there is no-one there at all, meaning that the person is a *gornicht*. This is a compliment and not an insult, because the *halacha* is always *ki'stam mishnah*.

Answer (score 1):

A simple compromise is expressed clearly in [Rabbeinu Bachya on Bereishis 46:32](https://www.sefaria.org/Rabbeinu_Bahya%2C_Bereshit.46.32.2?ven=Torah_Commentary_by_Rabbi_Bachya_ben_Asher,_trans._Eliyahu_Munk,_1998.&vhe=Midrash_Rabbeinu_Bachya_%5Bben_Asher%5D._Warsaw,_1878&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> וילך אחרי אליהו וישרתהו. וכן היה בלי ספק מנהג בני הנביאים בדור ההוא
>
> We go after (i.e. we use the name) Eliyahu (i.e. the name in full), and similarly also "Belly" - although there was a doubt about this custom amongst the children of the prophets in that generation.

In other words, Rabbeinu Bachya explains that it is proper to use the full name Eliyahu and now the additional "Belly" is allowed despite it being a sofek in earlier generations when they didn't feel it was proper. Now due to Yeridas Hadoros the correct appellation is "Eliyahu Belly".

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: .עולם חסד יבנה.